# NestJS Entity class - 'methodname' is not a function

Tags: javascript, class, nestjs

I'm tackling a NestJS course and it's just a bit outdated and at the moment the requirement is to have a "Create" method on the entity class, I can see that the instructor is able to have it functioning but I keep getting an error.

```
@Entity()
@Unique('task_index_uq', ['title'])
export class Task extends Repository<Task> {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  description: string;

  @Column()
  status: TaskStatus;

  async createTask(createTaskDto: CreateTaskDto): Promise<Task> {
    const { title, description } = createTaskDto;

    const task = this.create({
      title,
      description,
      status: TaskStatus.OPEN,
    });

    await this.save(task);
    return task;
  }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Why is your entity extending a repository?

Comment: as I said, the course was outdated a bit and I did have a repository with a deprecated decorator, @EntityRepository and I found that solution to make a custom repo, is that bad? what is the right way?

Comment: Nothing wrong with a custom repository

Comment: you can create custom repos, but not with `@EntityRepository()` anymore. There's another way. https://typeorm.io/

Comment: I agree with @JayMcDoniel. Create that method in other class like custom repository or service.